# Regex to match "<seven digits> - <filename>" with only one set of seven digits

Tags: regex, powershell

I've been trying to write a regex that will match a filename appended with a seven-digit numerical identifier followed by a hyphen, for example `1234567 - filename.pdf`

The filename can be any collection of filename-valid characters.

So far I have the regex `^[0-9]{7} - .*`, which matches with the string, but it also matches with `7654321 - 1234567 - filename.pdf` and `3214567 - 7654321 - 1234567 - filename.pdf` and so on.

Is there a regex that will only match strings with one set of digits and a hyphen? Something like `^[0-9]{7} -{1} .*`

Comment: Maybe `^[0-9]{7} - (?![0-9]{7} - ).*`? If whitespace amount is arbitrary, it won't work though.

Comment: There's only ever going to be one space before and after the hyphen.
Mind explaining what this does? Does it make sure whatever follows the 7-digit string isn't another 7-digit string?

Comment: See [the regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%5b0-9%5d%7b7%7d+-+%28%3f!%5b0-9%5d%7b7%7d+-+%29.*&i=7654321+-+1234567+-+filename.pdf%0d%0a3214567+-+7654321+-+1234567+-+filename.pdf%0d%0a1234567+-+filename.pdf&o=m). `(?![0-9]{7} - )` fails the match once 7 digits, space, `-` and space are found after the first 7 digits, space, `-`, space.

Comment: That's brilliant, thank you! I doubt there'll be any filenames with the same 7 digit/space/hyphen/space format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may add a negative lookahead:

```
^[0-9]{7} - (?![0-9]{7} - ).* 
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E%5B0-9%5D%7B7%7D%20-%20%28%3F!%5B0-9%5D%7B7%7D%20-%20%29.%2A&i=7654321%20-%201234567%20-%20filename.pdf%0D%0A3214567%20-%207654321%20-%201234567%20-%20filename.pdf%0D%0A1234567%20-%20filename.pdf&o=m).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `[0-9]{7}` - 7 digits
- `-`  - space, `-`, space
- `(?![0-9]{7} - )` - a negative lookahead that failing the match if there are 7 digits, space, `-` and a space immediately to the right of the current location
- `.*` - any 0+ chars, as many as possible